# How to use Event loop in JS to construct a debounce function?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to construct a debounce function definition to give following results. My following code prints the following.

```
'hi'
'hi'
'hi'
'hi'
```

I am struggling to figure out how I can leverage `interval` to contain `x` as `undefined` and once this expires again the function returns `'hi'`

```
function debounce(callback, interval) {
  return () =>{
    let x = callback();
    setTimeout(()=>{
    x = callback();
    },interval);
    return x;
  }
}

// Expectation running below statements
function giveHi() { return 'hi'; }
const giveHiSometimes = debounce(giveHi, 3000);

console.log(giveHiSometimes()); // -> 'hi'
setTimeout(function() { console.log(giveHiSometimes()); }, 2000); // -> undefined
setTimeout(function() { console.log(giveHiSometimes()); }, 4000); // -> undefined
setTimeout(function() { console.log(giveHiSometimes()); }, 8000); // -> 'hi'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a `calledRecently` flag, which gets set to true when the timeout callback runs. When the timeout callback runs, set another timeout which runs after the interval is up to reset `calledRecently` to false:

```js
function debounce(callback, interval) {
  let calledRecently = false;
  let intervalId;
  return () => {
    const result = calledRecently ? undefined : callback();
    calledRecently = true;
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    intervalId = setTimeout(() => {
      calledRecently = false;
    }, interval);
    return result;
  }
}

const giveHiSometimes = debounce(() => 'hi', 3000);

console.log(giveHiSometimes()); // -> 'hi'
setTimeout(function() { console.log(giveHiSometimes()); }, 2000); // -> undefined
setTimeout(function() { console.log(giveHiSometimes()); }, 4000); // -> undefined
setTimeout(function() { console.log(giveHiSometimes()); }, 8000); // -> 'hi'
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're after [leading edge (immediate) debouncing](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/) where an initial event is fired, but batched events after it are debounced.

There are a few ways of writing this, including `setTimeout` and `Date.now` but it all comes down to moving a `lastAttempt` variable of some sort outside of the closure and not re-triggering the callback unless the cooldown time has passed without any attempts to call the function being made. Writing it without `setInterval` seems cleaner to me.

I'd also add an `...args` parameter to the function returned from your `leadingDebounce` function. This lets you pass parameters into the function if you want.

```js
const leadingDebounce = (fn, cooldown) => {
  let lastAttempt = 0;
  
  return (...args) => {
    if (Date.now() - lastAttempt > cooldown) {
      fn(...args);
    }

    lastAttempt = Date.now();
  };
};

const debounced = leadingDebounce(() => console.log("hi"), 3000);

debounced();                                      // -> 'hi'
setTimeout(() => console.log(debounced()), 2000); // -> undefined
setTimeout(() => console.log(debounced()), 4000); // -> undefined
setTimeout(debounced, 8000);                      // -> 'hi'
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the similar question ggorlen. That really helped me understand better.